# How to update quadmesh when figure changes size

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, mesh, colorbar

i have the following problem in matplotlib (using python 3.x). I want to use a qudmesh with a frame that changes constantly. if the frame has the same initial size, that is ok. the problem is my frame will change sizes, and i have a problem updating this info.

the following code snippet is a small simulation to show how my problem comes in. when frame2 comes i want to update the data so that the figure updates all the sizes.

i get the following error. `TypeError: Dimensions of A (4, 4) are incompatible with X (4) and/or Y (4)`

I feel like i am not updating the correct variables here, the variable `array` updates correctly (i tried it when the frame was of the same size). the problem is with the vectors x and y. any idea how to solve this?

thanks

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import QuadMesh
from random import random

frame1 = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
frame2 = np.array([[1,2,3, 9], [4,5,6, 9], [7,8,9, 9], [10,11,12,13]])
x = np.array([[1,2,3]])*random()
y = np.array([[1],[2],[3]])*random()

x2 = np.array([[1,2,3, 4]])*random()
y2 = np.array([[1],[2],[3], [4]])*random()

index = 0

with plt.style.context("classic"):
    plt.ion()
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    m: QuadMesh = ax.pcolormesh(x, y, frame1, shading='nearest')
    fig.colorbar(m)

    while True:
        frame = frame1 if index <= 25 else frame2

        if index <=25:
            m.update({'array': frame})
        else:
            m.update({'array': frame, 'axes': [x2, y2]})
        print(index)
        index += 1

        plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will now update the x and y arrays when the frame changes size, and the error will be fixed.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import QuadMesh
from random import random

frame1 = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
frame2 = np.array([[1,2,3, 9], [4,5,6, 9], [7,8,9, 9], [10,11,12,13]])
x = np.array([[1,2,3]])*random()
y = np.array([[1],[2],[3]])*random()

x2 = np.array([[1,2,3, 4]])*random()
y2 = np.array([[1],[2],[3], [4]])*random()

index = 0

with plt.style.context("classic"):
    plt.ion()
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    m: QuadMesh = ax.pcolormesh(x, y, frame1, shading='nearest')
    fig.colorbar(m)

    while True:
        frame = frame1 if index <= 25 else frame2
        axes = [x, y] if index <= 25 else [x2, y2]

        m.update({'array': frame, 'axes': axes})
        print(index)
        index += 1

        plt.show()
```

hope this code will be working....

Comment: thanks @kapila shobit. i get this error though: ValueError: Can not reset the axes.  You are probably trying to re-use an artist in more than one Axes which is not supported